# NameError: name 'qtd' is not defined appears when i try to make an if

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, nameerror, enumerate

I'm trying to figure out the position of a value in a worksheet, and I have that value stored in a variable.

```
list = df['Quantidade de Cotas'].tolist()
qtd = 2136252.54442995
print(qtd)
```

The value of the variable is 2136252.54442995, so it is defined

```
> 2136252.54442995
```

But if I try to execute an if

```
res = [i for i,j in enumerate(list) if j == qtd]

print(res)
```

this error appears saying that the variable is not defined

```
> NameError: name 'qtd' is not defined
```

---

If I run the exact same code, but instead of the variable, put her value, the if works and returns the correct position within the list

```
list = df['Quantidade de Cotas'].tolist()
qtd = 2136252.54442995
print(qtd)

> 2136252.54442995

res = [i for i,j in enumerate(list) if j == 2136252.54442995]

print(res)

> [0]
```

Could someone help me to make this code work this way?

```
list = df['Quantidade de Cotas'].tolist()
qtd = 2136252.54442995
res = [i for i,j in enumerate(list) if j == qtd]

print(res)

> [0]
```

Comment: Try to create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show it as **properly formatted text** in the question.

Comment: `qtd` is not defined anywhere in the code above? *The value of the variable is 2136252.54442995, so it is defined* - where is it defined?

Comment: qtd is defined just above in the code, the problem is not that the variable does not exist, it is that it cannot be read.

Comment: Why cant it be read? You seem to be leaving out some key information/context

Comment: The code was initialized through an interface, but i ended up finding out that the problem was tkinter (used to create the interface). For some reason when running the code directly without the interface it works. I couldn't find out why this happened, I'm analyzing what it could be

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Quantidade de Cotas': [10, 20, 10, 40, 50]})

list = df['Quantidade de Cotas'].tolist()
# qtd = 2136252.54442995
qtd = 10

res = [i for i,j in enumerate(list) if j == qtd]
print(res)
```

**Outout: [0, 2]**

your code is correct but ensure you define `'qtd'` before using it in the list comprehension.